react native vision camera always get empty devices on ios simiulator
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { useCameraDevices, Camera } from 'react-native-vision-camera';

const App = () => {
  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  console.log(devices);
  const device = devices.back;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  const requestCameraPermission = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const permission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();

    if (permission == 'denied') {
      console.log('Permission not granted');
      await Linking.openSettings();
    }
  }, []);

  function renderCamera() {
    if (device == null) {
      console.log('device is null');

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Camera not working</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      <View>
        <Camera device={device} isActive={true} enableZoomGesture />
      </View>;
    }
  }

  return <View>{renderCamera()}</View>;
};

export default App;

version
"react-native-vision-camera": "^4.5.1"
